# Apply a Regex between string README_* and REAME_IMP_*

Tags: regex, string, colors, background-color, ls

I use `grc` to colorify the results of `ls` command.

For the moment, I have the following rule to display the text in white foreground on blue background. I did for this :

```
#README
regexp=(README_[^.]*$)
colours=on_blue blink
```

Now I would like for string beginning by `README_IMP_*` (star `*` represent any other string) to display in white foreground on red background.

I did in the same file :

```
#README_IMP
regexp=(README_IMP[^.]*$)
colours=on_red blink
```

But the issue is even I type `$ touch README_IMP_any_string` , the text will be displayed unfortunately in white foreground on blue background, that is to say, the first rule `regexp=(README_[^.]*$)` has the priority on `regexp=(README_IMP[^.]*$)`.

How to distinguish, with an appropriate regexp (with `grc`), the string `README_any_string` from `README_IMP_any_string` ?

PS: you can take a look at examples of regexp `grc` engine on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371668/grc-inside-terminal-with-different-colors-into-terminal-as-a-function-of-files

**UPDATE 1:** following the advice of `@Ludovic Kuty`, If I invert the order between the 2 rules like this :

```
#README_IMP
regexp=(README_IMP[^.]*$)
colours=on_red blink

# README
regexp=(README_[^.]*$)
colours=on_blue blink
```

The second rule seems to overwrite the first one and this is illustrated on this figure :

[image: difference between README_* and READ_IMP_*]

As you can see, the file `READ_IMP_1` is in white on blue and not white on red as expected.

**UPDATE 2:** From what I have seen, the file `conf.ls` is readed from the top to the bottom and I can't explain why the negative `regexp=(README_(?!IMP)[^.]*$)` is not matched when I create a `README_string` where string is any string excepted `IMP`.

For example, in my `conf.ls`, I have set for the moment :

```
# README with no IMP after
regexp=(README_(?!IMP)[^.]*$)
colours=on_blue blink

# README_IMP
regexp=(README_IMP[^.]*$)
colours=on_red blink
```

If a create a file named README_for_example, then this latter will be in 'on_red blink' color whereas the other `README_*` with `*` not string containing `IMP` , will be in white :

Why `regexp=(README_(?!IMP)[^.]*$)` is not matched in this case ?

Maybe there is a conflict between `dircolors` and `grc` ?

Here the beginning of ~/.dircolors :

```
#NORMAL 01;37       # global default, although everything should be something.
FILE 01;37         # normal file
DIR 32       # directory
LINK 01;36      # symbolic link
FIFO 40;33      # pipe
SOCK 01;35      # socket
BLK 40;33;01    # block device driver
CHR 40;33;01    # character device driver
```

As you can see, I commented the `NORMAL` line, believing that it could make a change but actually, no consequences.

It looks like the lest regexp rule had the priority and is applied even the match is wrong ...

**UPDATE 3:**

Given the fact that no one is able to suggest a solution, I think that I am going to have to modif ls.c and recompile following previous post. I understand, it is like to use a nuclear bomb to kill a chicken but it seems that I have not other alternatives.

**UPDATE 4:** Here the last attempt suggested by  `@NechesStich` :

```
# README_IMP
regexp=(README_IMP[^.]*$)
colours=on_red blink

# README with no IMP after
regexp=README_[^.I][^.]*$|README_[^.][^.M][^.]*$|README_[^.][^.][^.P][^.]*$|README_I$|README_IM$
colours=on_blue blink
```

Unfortunately, the distinction between `README_*` (where * doesn't start by IMP) and `README_IMP_*` (with * any string).

I get the following result :

[image: No distinction between README_* and README_IMP_*]

As you can see, README_* is well recognize wheread `README_IMP_1` is colrized in white :

I think the conflict between the white color between for normal files and from grc come from ~/.dircolors :

```
#NORMAL 01;37       # global default, although everything should be something.
FILE 01;37         # normal file
DIR 32       # directory
LINK 01;36      # symbolic link
FIFO 40;33      # pipe
SOCK 01;35      # socket
BLK 40;33;01    # block device driver
CHR 40;33;01    # character device driver
```

I don't understand why `dircolors` has the priority before `grc`.

It deserves more investigations, I am going to do other tests.

**UPDATE 5** Here an extract from documentation [doc grc](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/%7Egarabik/software/grc/README.txt) of `grc` about the policy of string colorified :

```
**count** is one of words: once, more, stop, previous, block or unblock

- **once** means that if the regexp is matched, its first occurrence is coloured and the program will continue with other regexp's.
- **more** means that if there are multiple matches of the regexp in one line, all of them will be coloured.
- **stop** means that the regexp will be coloured and program will move to the next line (i.e. ignoring other regexp's)
- **previous** means the count will be the same as for the previous line
- **block** marks a start of a multiline block of text, coloured with the same colour
- **unblock**, obviously, marks the end of such a block

example:

    # this is probably a pathname
    regexp=/[\w/\.]+
    colour=green
    count=more

this will match `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin/`, `/etc/init.d/syslogd` and similar strings and paint it with green.

Another example:

    regexp=^-{1,2}\s{0,1}$
    colours=red
    count=block
    -
    regexp=^\s{0,5}$
    colours=default
    count=unblock

this will turn all correctly formatted mail signatures red.

Regular expressions are evaluated from top to bottom, this allows nested and overlapped expressions. (e.g. you colour everything inside parentheses with one colour, and if a following expression matches the text inside parentheses, it will be also coloured).
```

Can you see an application in my case ?

Comment: `regexp=(README_IMP_[^.]*$)` <-- presumably this is what you intended to use for the second case?

Comment: yes, this is all for the files beginning by `README_IMP_`, I mean `README_IMP_*` with `*` any string.

Comment: Could you just swap the order of the rules ? More specific first.

Comment: @LudovicKuty . You can see the results in my **UPDATE** above. It doesn't seem to have effects on the results, see the figure. Regards

Comment: I am neither able to reproduce the problem nor making `grc` work correctly. I use a directory with two files: `README_IMP_any_string` and `README_any_string`. The regexes are yours (just `on_red` and `on_blue`) in `~/.grc/ls.conf` and the test is `ls -l | grcat ls.conf`. What I get is a red background for `README_IMP_any_string` and nothing for the other one. So it is difficult for me to help since I cannot reproduce your problem and cannot even make it work correctly.

Comment: @LudovicKuty . Thanks for trying to help me. My command that makes appear everything is an alias : `l='grc -es --colour=auto ls --color -Gh -C -lrt'`. Maybe you will be able to reproduce the issue with this command.

Comment: You could distinguish between regex by using negative lookahead `(?! ... )` but even that does not work for me but maybe it will for you. Example: `regexp=README_(?!IMP_)[^.]*$`

Comment: @LudovicKuty . I don't understand, your reasoning is logic, this should normallly work... disapointed.. Is it worth to launch a bounty for that ?

Comment: Good idea. It will give it more visibility

Comment: I finally decided to launch a bounty. If by chance, someone could know the trick ... Regards

Comment: Can you try with ```regexp=README_[^.I][^.]*$|README_[^.][^.M][^.]*$|README_[^.][^.][^.P][^.]*$|README_I$|README_IM$``` it should be equivalent to ```regexp=README_(?!IMP_)[^.]*$``` but dosen't use negative lookahead

Comment: @NechesStich . Thanks for your help. You can see the results in my **UPDATE 4**. Unfortunately, I don't understand why dircolors has the priority before grc. regards

Comment: @NechesStich. I found out somtething for each test : the last regexp in **conf.ls** in file is always the rule applied when I list the files. If i set a regexp with **colours=on_blue blink**, this will be blue on white. If I set in last the rule **colours=on_red blink**, this will be red on white. it is weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the sourcecode on https://github.com/garabik/grc/blob/master/grcat (lines 157-165)

You can see grc dosen't consider lines that start with # or \n to start new rules only lines with other non letter characters, and if you look at other examples they separate their rules with =======

This is why only your last rule ever applied since they weren't separated properly they were overwriting each other

It should work when separated like this

```
# README with no IMP after
regexp=README_(?!IMP)[^.]*$
colours=on_blue blink
=======
# README_IMP
regexp=README_IMP[^.]*$
colours=on_red blink
```